# How can I get this data-tag-id from this table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, selector

I've ran into a problem while coding.
I have pretty big table with a lot of rows.
I'm getting data from this table using this piece of code:

```
let tag1 = document.querySelector('body > div.l-global-width.l-container-primary > div > div.l-container-col2.box-userprofile > section > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)').innerText;
```

The problem is, i need to get id of this tag from this table.

```
<tr data-tag-id="7" role="row">
<td class="ord">1</td>
<td>Komedia</td>
<td class="number">2</td>
<td class="number">10</td>
<td class="number">131</td>
<td class="number" data-sort-value="7.44">7,44</td>
<td class="number" data-sort-value="7.21">7,21</td>
<td class="number" data-sort-value="34434">573h&nbsp;54m</td>
</tr>
```

..and as you can guess, I have no idea how to do it. I've tried a few things, but none of them worked for me, and I'm not experienced enough to come with another ideas.

Can anyone help me solve it? I appreciate all the help.

Comment: ID? what id? `7`? Depending on what condition? Also, why you use such brittle and complicated seectors?

Comment: It's not my website, i'm coding a scraper tho, and yes, i need to get this id=7.

Comment: OK. 7. Depending on what condition? It's a row. There could be a myriad of other rows with other IDs. Why you need just that 7 one?

Comment: Yeah, i just somehow need to get this id from exactly this table, to associate it with the tag name, but i have no clue how to do it. It's probably simple, but I really have no idea how to get it basing on the selector i've posted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute selector `[]`:

```
const ELS_tagId = document.querySelectorAll("tr[data-tag-id]");
```

which will give you a collection of all `<tr>`s with `data-tag-id` elements.
To loop them:

```
ELS_tagId.forEach(function(el) {
  console.log(el.dataset.tagId); // among which you'll get also that "7"
});
```

PS: notice that dash-separated HTML data-* tags are used as camelCase in JS `tag-id` → `tagId`